# ps2pdf does not work at all

Tags: psfrag, ps2pdf, ps

I am using Texmaker 5.0.3 with Miktex 2.9 and compiling from ps to pdf does not work. When I compile document with Latex+dvips+View PS I got expected output in PS, but when I use Latex+dvips+ps2pdf+View PDF I have only `process exited with errors` message, without any pdf as compilation result, and dvi file which is result of that compilation shows some mess at the place of figure which use psfrag. I cannot find in log file what exactly the error is.

Also when I try `ps2pdf` command in Windows terminal, it does not show any message, but it also do nothing.

And when I try form terminal `ps2pdf -v -` it shows nothing, but when I try `rungs -v` I got answer:

```
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25 (2018-09-13)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

What I should do to enable ps2pdf to work?

There is all files and results of compile with Latex+dvips+ps2pdf+View PDF Quick build option in TExMaker.
https://files.fm/u/jg4ncqk3y

Comment: Can you post the TeX file content as `MWE`?

Comment: I added full simple example, it is still the problem which I described.

Comment: your example compiles for me with a current miktex. But your miktex is 2 years old, and you won't find many people with this version.

Comment: I updated it, it gives the same result. After I uninstalled MikTex and than installed it, it is again the same.

Comment: What version of Ghostscript are you using?